# How should I iterate over an array in emberjs and update the route to reflect the change?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to make an image slideshow with next/previous buttons but I don't understand how I should make it work all together. Can someone help me glue the pieces?

This is how the data looks like:

```
{
  "newsitems": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Amai het wordt bangelijk!",
      "mediaitems": [
        {
          "id": "AEOpX8tmiUI",
          "newsitem_id": "1",
          "value": "AEOpX8tmiUI"
        },
        {
          "id": "kxopViU98Xo",
          "newsitem_id": "1",
          "value": "kxopViU98Xo"
        },
        {
          "id": "1",
          "newsitem_id": "1",
          "value": "1276468632.JPG"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "newsitem_id": "1",
          "value": "1278286227.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to let the user iterate the mediaitems array. So when the user enters a route:

```
http://domain.com/#!/newsitems/1/overlay/kxopViU98Xo
```

That item should be in the center of the screen and a next/prev button should take the user to the next or previous item in the array.

This is how my route looks like:

```
App.MediaitemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Mediaitem.find(params.mediaitem_id);
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('overlay').set('content', model);
  },

  renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    this.render('overlay', { into: 'application', outlet: 'overlay', controller: 'overlay'});
  }
});
```

And this is the ObjectController for the overlay:

```
App.OverlayController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  prev: function(){
    var mediaitems = this.get('model').get('newsitem.mediaitems');
    var currentMediaItemID = this.get('model').get('id');

    var currentIndex = 0;
    var i = 0;

    mediaitems.forEach(function(object){
      if(object.get('id') == currentMediaItemID) currentIndex = i;
      i++;
    });

    // How should I transition to the next object?
  }
});
```

The route renders a template called "overlay' which has two actions: "prev" and "next" (I'm only showing prev in my controller to keep things clean).

My two concerns are: the code to lookup the currentitem in the array (and code to get the next or previous object) just feels 'wrong' or overly 'complex'.

I don't know how to update the route and redirect to the next/previous item.

Some more useful stuff:

Handlebars template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="overlay">
  <div class="overlay">
    <a {{action "prev" target="controller"}}>PREV</a>
    <a {{action "next" target="controller"}}>NEXT</a>
  </div>
</script>
```

My models:

```
App.Newsitem = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),

  mediaitems: DS.hasMany('App.Mediaitem')
});

App.Mediaitem = DS.Model.extend({
  value: DS.attr('string'),

  newsitem: DS.belongsTo('App.Newsitem')
});
```

My routes:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('newsitems', function(){
    this.resource('newsitem', {path:':newsitem_id'}, function(){
      this.resource('mediaitem', {path:'/overlay/:mediaitem_id'});
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Ever figure this out?